# Is it possible to check if an Entity is "Activity" enabled in Dynamics CRM programatically?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When creating a custom Entity in Dynamics CRM 2013, you have the option of enabling Activities for that entity (i.e. in the Entity configuration screen, you can check the "Activities" checkbox).

This allows Activity records to be linked to the new custom Entity.

We have a CRM plugin developed in C# that needs to check if a custom entity is "Activity" enabled, as the plugin needs to create an Activity record linked to the custom entity record.

Is there a way to check if an Entity is "Activity" enabled programatically?

Comment: I did a quick check and it looks like you will have to evaluate the 1:n Relationships of your entity to find out. So yes, there is definitely a way to find out programmatically. It is merely a matter of best performance on how to retrieve this information. If you are interested I could post a basic sample for you to get started.

Comment: Hi Filburt, yes that was it, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `RetrieveEntityRequest` to find out if an entity is enabled for activities. The `RetrieveEntityResponse` contains an `EntityMetadata` object with in it the `OneToManyRelationships`.

When the entity has a relationship with *activitypointer* entities, it is enabled for activities.

Code example:

```
var metaResponse = (RetrieveEntityResponse)proxy.Execute(new RetrieveEntityRequest
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Relationships,
    LogicalName = "account",
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = false
});

bool isActivityEnabled =
    metaResponse.EntityMetadata.OneToManyRelationships
    .Any(r => r.ReferencingEntity == "activitypointer");
```

> Do not set `RetrieveAsIsPublished = true`. Of course setting this property can as well be omitted, but I left it in sake of clarity. Credits go to SimonM, see comments section below.

Comment: Looks good. Is it possible that an entity record is 'activity' enabled, but does not have any linked activitypointer records, then resulting in a false negative?

Comment: No that's not possible. EntityMetadata gives you details about the data model of your Dynamics CRM tenant. This has nothing to do with the data that is actually present in the database.

Comment: This did the job, spent hours looking for a boolean in metadata before this. Great answer thanks!

Comment: Found this answer via web search, so for others that land here: Not a good idea to use `RetrieveAsIfPublished = true`, especially in code that runs often. This flag will bypass the metadata cache and evaluate all configurations to determine what the entity looks like *if* I published any unpublished changes - it's an expensive query that doesn't make sense unless you're really trying to see what the metadata would look like before publishing.

Comment: @SimonM: good point! Did not know that when writing this answer.