# How can I get the EntityMetadata.HasActivities Property to populate?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In Dynamics 365 Online I'm trying to get a list of all tables can have Activities.

I thought to use the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.EntityMetadata` class, and retrieve the [HasActivities property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entitymetadata.hasactivities?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-xrm-sdk-metadata-entitymetadata-hasactivities).

Using this code I tried retrieving it as part of a `RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest`, and also a `RetrieveEntityRequest`, but the value of `HasActivities` is always `null`:

```
var req = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity 
};
var all = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)svc.Execute(req);

var hasActivities = all.EntityMetadata
    .Where(m => m.HasActivities == true)
    .Select(m => m.LogicalName)
    .OrderBy(n => n)
    .ToList();
///hasActivities count is 0 because m.HasActivities is null for all entries.

var account = all.EntityMetadata.First(m => m.LogicalName == "account");
var req2 = new RetrieveEntityRequest
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
    MetadataId = (Guid)account.MetadataId
};
var accountAll = (RetrieveEntityResponse)svc.Execute(req2);
var accountHasActivites = accountAll.EntityMetadata.HasActivities;
///accountHasActivities is still null
```

I checked XrmTookit's Metadata Browser, and discovered that it shows as false there for the Account table:
[image: xrmToolbox screenshot]

Of course Accounts have been able to have Activities since time immemorial, as shown in the maker UI:
[image]

I also checked the `MetadataSchema.Entity` table in the SQL database of a v8.0 (CRM 2016) instance I have locally.
Turns out it doesn't have a `HasActivities` column...

In SQL I also checked the view `dbo.EntityView` and some other `dbo.Entity*` views - they all lacked a `HasActivities` column.

I also installed Microsoft's [Metadata Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/browse-your-metadata?view=op-9-1). It shows no HasActivities property:
[image: metadata Browser]

So, I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to use the SDK to populate the `EntityMetadata.HasActivities` property?
2. How does the maker UI correctly populate the "Make this table an option when Creating a new Activity" checkbox?

As per Guido's comment below, it turns out this appears to only be an issue in v8.2 (specifically v8.2.19.13). In Dynamics Online (v9+), HasActivities is working fine. Thanks Guido!

Comment: I just checked in a trial and the metadata returns HasActivities true for the correct entities, I also executed your LINQ query https://imgur.com/a/Zd9buOQ

Comment: by the way, for the RetrieveEntityRequest you can use LogicalName instead of MetadataId to fetch the entity

Comment: Thanks Guido. Good catch. I was trying against a v8.2 on-prem instance. I tried against an online instance and HasActivities is populated. It seems that against v8.2 it's always `null` (via the SDK and in XrmToolbox Metadata Browser).

Comment: maybe it's a bug of the specific rollup version installed inside that 8.2 on-prem instance

Comment: Could be... for the record it's v8.2.19.13

Comment: You may want to check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768264/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-entity-is-activity-enabled-in-dynamics-crm-progr/29771270#29771270